# How to plot data which are coming from TCP?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tcp, tcpclient

I am trying to read data over TCP, save it and plot it, all at the same time. So far I am reading the data and saving to a text file but I have problem with plotting it. The data is coming as string and I could not figure out how to convert it to int or float. Or how to pass the values into an array to plot.

Here are my codes:

Server:

```
import socket 
import mraa
import time
import numpy

host = '172.20.61.19'
port = 5000

x = mraa.Gpio(20)
x.dir(mraa.DIR_OUT)

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()

print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
while True:
        x.write(1)
        time.sleep(2)
        data = x.read()
        print str(data)
        c.send(str(data))
        x.write(0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        data = x.read()
        print str(data)
        c.send(str(data))
s.close()
```

Client:

```
import socket 
from collections import deque
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

host = '172.20.61.19'
port = 5000

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,port))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print data
    secPlot = ax.plot(int(data), 'b-')
    fig.canvas.draw()
s.close()
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with naked binary data from TCP is messy. You may want to serialise your data on one side so that it can travel through TCP connections and be restored on the other, then you may want to define a separator for splitting sections of the serialised data. For example, you can serialise the data into JSON format, and treat `'\0'` as the separator. So on the server side, you send:

`{'data':[1,2,3,4,5]}\0{'data':[6,7,8]}\0{'data':...`

And on the client side, you keep receive until reaching '\0', convert the received part back into Python dict, and continue receive the next trunk.

Take a look at https://github.com/mdebbar/jsonsocket/blob/master/jsonsocket.py for a great simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this example, I am creating a connection to a TCP socket and after I am creating an animated graph to print the information (to avoid use the while True to read data from the server).

```
    # get the information ( tcp connector, you can keep your client)  
    reader = DataReader()
    reader.connect(ip=args.ip, port= args.port)
    # configure x axis (time data) 
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator())
    # define a figure
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # this method is in charge of read the data
    values = [[],[]]
    def animate(i):
       # obtain a message from the socket ( s.recv(1024) ) 
       message = reader.get_message()
       data_x = message['x']
       data_y = message['y']
       values[0].append(data_x)
       values[1].append(data_y)
       # clear graph 
       ax.clear()
       # plot the information         
       ax.plot(values[0],values[1],'o-', label= 'my data')
       # legends
       ax.legend()
       xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
       ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    # animate (this line help us replace the while true)
    # the interval is the time refresh for our graph 
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500)
    # finally we show the image
    plt.show()
```